# Switching threshold of CMOS inverter

Tags: cmos, vlsi, cadence

How to find the switching threshold of CMOS inverter from it's transfer characteristics in Cadence Virtuoso?

Comment: Which one? supply a part number. Cmos usually has a Vil at 1.3V and a ViH at 3.7V

Answer (score 1):

If you have the transfer characteristics for an inverter in cadence virtuoso. Then the switching threshold is the point on the curve where vin=vout, so draw the line vin=vout over the curve and where it intersects the transfer curve for the inverter will give you the switching threshold.
[image]